# Automating an fmpeg task

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg

I'm looking for help automating a FFMPEG workflow on OSX.

I want to have a hotfolder where when I drop an .mp4 and it starts a merge. It adds a card to the front, and one to the back. The front card is the same as is the back (but the front and back are different).

I've used something like this to output a .mkv successfully, but I can't figure out how to output a .mp4

```
ffmpeg -i front.mp4 -i main.mp4 -i end.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0]2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mkv
```

Resulting Log for LLogan

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Mark/FFMPEG/CARD/start.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1737 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1605 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Mark/FFMPEG/RAW/body.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-04-12T01:12:58.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 1.2.0 2018122200
  Duration: 00:43:51.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2405 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2264 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-12T01:12:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-12T01:12:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Mark/FFMPEG/CARD/end.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2020-06-09T19:53:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:28.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2584 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2479 kb/s, 23.96 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-09T19:53:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-09T19:53:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -n -i front.mp4 -i main.mp4 -i end.mp4`. This command is only to get file info: its does not output a file. It will provide useful info about the inputs and your `ffmpeg` version. This info is required to provide an answer that you can copy and paste. Copy the **complete** log from that command. [Edit] your question and paste the complete log into your question. Ignore the `At least one output file must be specified error` in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hard time getting MP4 "merges" in a single command line.  But, this approach definitely works for me.  Put it into a shell script, like merge.sh:

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
        printf "USAGE: $0 <mp4-files>\n"
        exit
fi

if [ -f merge.txt ]
then
    rm merge.txt    
fi

for file in "$@"
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]
  then
    echo "file '"`pwd`/"$file'" >> merge.txt
  fi
done

basename=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/'`
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i merge.txt -c copy "$basename.merged.mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me immensely!