# How to recombine a movie file created in 1999 by Split it?

Tags: windows, mac

I have split a movie file in 1999 on a Mac computer by Split It software. Now I want to combine the parts to watch the movie on Windows.

Comment: Use *copy* with the /b switch to concatenate two or more files; e.g. "copy /b vid1.avi + vid2.avi vidjoined.avi"    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy

Comment: Are you on a Mac nowadays? Or a Windows system.

Comment: I am using Windows System

Comment: Not sure that a simple file concatenation would work.  That's interesting, but I would think that each file has data (like the metadata) that you can't have 2 copies of in the final file, not to mention the location of that data in the file would be in the wrong location.  Try using ffmpeg's merge function.  There are example of its use over on Stack Overflow, some of which I've posted, alongside many other people.

Comment: Oh, looks like my ffmpeg-merge answer is here on this site, not SO.  https://superuser.com/questions/1561679/automating-an-fmpeg-task/1561857?noredirect=1#comment2377915_1561857